Higher Coherences and Maps from Colimits
In higher category theory there is the important mantra that commutativities are additional data and not just a property as in $1$-category theory. So the following question I'm proposing will probably have a counterexample:
Question. Let $\mathscr{C}$ be an $\infty$-category with $c \in \mathscr{C}$ and consider a functor $F:(\mathbb{N}, \leq) \to \mathscr{C}$. A natural transformation $F \Rightarrow \mathrm{const}_c$ corresponds to a map $\operatorname{colim} F \to c$. Is this map already determined by all the maps $F(i) \to c$? In other words, consider two natural transformations $\alpha, \alpha'$ which agree on the maps but differ on higher simplices - do we get the same map $\operatorname{colim}{F} \to c$ up to homotopy?
The idea I'm basing this on is that the space of compositions is contractible and the higher information is essentially the data of compositions, so it sounds like one can take all these homotopies to make all of the natural transformations homotopic. But this is not quite rigorous and especially with similar features showing up in the cyclic invariance condition, I'm once again getting confused by higher coherences.

I posted an answer below, but I am now quite worried it contradicts the cyclic invariance theorem. I will think about this tomorrow.

I know what my mistake is: I only proved the answer to your question is yes if I assume all morphisms $F(i)\to c$ are equivalences (although not necessarily the identity equivalence). The general case should contradict cyclic invariance somehow, so I will add that answer in tomorrow.

I will prove the answer to your question is yes in case we assume that all maps $F(i)\to c$ are equivalences (though not necessarily identity morphisms). I originally failed to see that my solution below actually needs this hypothesis right at the start, so my large proof below does not actually answer your original question, but I think it is still interesting. It works also only because we are dealing with a very specific diagram shape.
The standing assumption is that all maps $F(i)\to c$ are equivalences.
As a prelude, note that it is false that two natural transformations $\alpha,\alpha'\colon F\Rightarrow\mathrm{const}_c$ of functors $\mathbb{N}\to\mathscr{C}$ must be homotopic if $\alpha(i)\simeq\alpha'(i)$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. This is due to the fact that we are asking (countably infinitely many times), given a diagram $\partial([1]\times[1])\to\mathscr{C}$ subject to the condition that the two vertical morphisms are identities, if any two fillers into a diagram $[1]\times[1]\to\mathscr{C}$ are homotopic relative to the boundary. This is not hard to disprove, basically because spheres are a thing. However, what is true is that we can find a homotopy between them relative two the two vertical identity morphisms, by precomposing, say, $\alpha$ with another filler of $\partial([1]\times[1])\to\mathscr{C}$. The latter fillers will induce in our case an automorphism $\psi\colon\mathrm{colim}\,F\to\mathrm{colim}\,F$ commuting with the two maps $\mathrm{colim}\,F\to c$ induced by $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$. It suffices to show that $\psi$ is an identity. As such, it suffices to show the following:

Claim. Suppose
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K_0 @>{f_0}>>K_1 @>{f_1}>>K_2 @>{f_2}>>\ldots
\end{CD}
$$
is a sequential diagram in an $\infty$-category $\mathscr{C}$, and suppose given a colimiting cocone $(g_i\colon K_i\to K_\infty)$ in $\mathscr{C}$. Given $2$-morphisms $\alpha_i$ filling in the diagrams
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K_i @>{f_i}>> K_{i+1}\\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @VV{\mathrm{id}}V\\
K_i @>{f_i}>> K_{i+1}
\end{CD}
$$
write $\psi\colon K_\infty\to K_\infty$ for the morphism on colimits induced by the collection $(\alpha_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then $\psi\simeq\mathrm{id}_{K_\infty}$.

This is the plan: we will first consider the ''universal example'' of the situation this claim, and show the claim holds in this case. Then we conclude the same must hold for any sequential colimit in any $\infty$-category.
We let $\Sigma^1$ be the categorical suspension of the anima $S^1$, i.e the $\infty$-category with two objects $\bot,\top$ and with $\Sigma^1(\bot,\bot)\simeq *\simeq\Sigma^1(\top,\top)$, $\Sigma^1(\bot,\top)\simeq S^1$ and $\Sigma^1(\top,\bot)\simeq\varnothing$. Define an $\infty$-category
$$
\mathsf{S}:\simeq\Sigma^1\bigsqcup_{\top, [0],\bot}\Sigma^1\bigsqcup_{\top, [0],\bot}\ldots,
$$
so that $\mathsf{S}$ is the $\infty$-category with natural numbers $0,1,2,\ldots$ as objects, and whose mapping anima are given by $\mathsf{S}(i,j)\simeq (S^1)^{j-i}$ if $i\leq j$, and by $\mathsf{S}(i,j)\simeq\varnothing$ if $i>j$. Pick your favourite point $s\in S^1$, and pick a loop $\alpha\colon s\simeq s$ in $S^1$ of degree $1$. We will later also consider $\alpha$ to be loop from $t$ to $t$ for any $t\in S^1$, but this will not cause problems.
In $\mathsf{S}$, we have now a sequential diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>{s}>> 1@>{s}>> 2@>{s}>> \ldots
\end{CD}
$$
and a commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0@>{s}>> 1@>{s}>> 2@>{s}>> \ldots\\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @V{\mathrm{id}}VV @V{\mathrm{id}}VV\\
0@>{s}>> 1@>{s}>> 2@>{s}>> \ldots
\end{CD}
$$
in which all the squares are filled by $\alpha$! Call this sequence $\mathbb{S}\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathsf{S}$ and call the diagram $\mathbb{D}_\alpha\colon\mathbb{N}\times[1]\to\mathsf{S}$. Under the Yoneda embedding $y\colon\mathsf{S}\hookrightarrow\mathrm{PSh}(\mathsf{S})$, we obtain a sequence $y\mathbb{S}\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathrm{PSh}(\mathsf{S})$ and a diagram $y\mathbb{D}_\alpha\colon\mathbb{N}\times[1]\to\mathrm{PSh}(\mathsf{S})$. Write $\mathbb{S}_\infty:\simeq\mathrm{colim}\,y\mathbb{S}$, and $\varphi\colon\mathbb{S}_\infty\to\mathbb{S}_\infty$ for the map induced by $y\mathbb{D}_\alpha$ on colimits. Our goal is to show that $\varphi\simeq\mathrm{id}$.
If we write $(y\mathbb{S})(i)$ for the evaluation of the presheaves appearing in $y\mathbb{S}$ at $i\in\mathbb{N}$, then the resulting sequence of anima is of the form
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\varnothing@>>>\varnothing@>>>\ldots@>>>\varnothing@>>> * @>{s}>> S^1 @>{(s,-)}>> (S^1)^2 @>{(s,-,-)}>>\ldots,
\end{CD}
$$
where the anima $*$ appears at stage $i$. Write the colimit of this sequence as $(S^1)^\infty$, so that $\mathbb{S}_\infty(i)\simeq(S^1)^\infty$ for any $i\in\mathbb{N}$. We can think of $(S^1)^\infty$ as the anima of sequences $t_kt_{k-1}\ldots t_1$ for $k\geq 0$ and $t_j\in S^1$, subject to the relation that $st_kt_{k-1}\ldots t_1$ is canonically homotopic to $t_kt_{k-1}\ldots t_1$. The canonical map $(S^1)^j\to (S^1)^\infty$ simply includes a sequence of length $j$ into this collection of sequences of arbitrary finite length.
The map $\varphi_i\colon\mathbb{S}_\infty(i)\to\mathbb{S}_\infty(i)$ is induced on colimits by the diagram $(y\mathbb{D}_\alpha)(i)$. We will show that $\varphi_i\simeq\mathrm{id}_{(S^1)^\infty}$. For simplicity, we take $i=0$, as the argument is the same in each case. We are considering the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
* @>{s}>> S^1 @>{(s,-)}>> (S^1)^2 @>{(s,-,-)}>>\ldots\\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @V{\mathrm{id}}VV @V{\mathrm{id}}VV\\
* @>{s}>> S^1 @>{(s,-)}>> (S^1)^2 @>{(s,-,-)}>>\ldots\\
\end{CD}
$$
in which each square is filled by $\alpha$. Define a homotopy $H_j$ filling the square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(S^1)^j @>>> (S^1)^\infty\\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @VV{\mathrm{id}}V\\
(S^1)^j @>>> (S^1)^\infty
\end{CD}
$$
as follows: $H_j$ sends a sequence $t_jt_{j-1}\ldots t_1$ to itself, via the path $(\alpha^{-1},\alpha^{-1},\ldots,\alpha^{-1})$ that performs $\alpha^{-1}$ on each factor $S^1$ of $(S^1)^j\subseteq(S^1)^\infty$. (Here, we consider $\alpha$ not only a loop from $s$ to $s$, but also from each $t_k$ to itself.) Direct verification shows that there is an identity higher homotopy identifying the composite
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(S^1)^j @>{(s,-,\ldots,-)}>> (S^1)^{j+1} @>>> (S^1)^\infty\\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @VV{\mathrm{id}}V @VV{\mathrm{id}}V\\
(S^1)^j @>{(s,-,\ldots,-)}>>(S^1)^{j+1} @>>> (S^1)^\infty
\end{CD}
$$
(with fillers $\alpha$ in the left square and $H_{j+1}$ in the right square)
with
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(S^1)^j @>>> (S^1)^\infty\\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @VV{\mathrm{id}}V\\
(S^1)^j @>>> (S^1)^\infty
\end{CD}
$$
(with filler $H_j$ in the square) for each $j\geq 0$. We pick this trivial higher homotopy! This witnesses that $\varphi_0\simeq\mathrm{id}_{(S^1)^\infty}$. (And as said, likewise that $\varphi_i\simeq\mathrm{id}_{(S^1)^\infty}$ for any $i\geq 0$.)
It remains to show that the higher coherences in the morphism $\varphi\colon\mathbb{S}_\infty\to\mathbb{S}_\infty$ of presheaves are also trivial. Given $u\in S^1$, seen as a morphism $i\to i+1$ in $\mathsf{S}$, we of course want to know now what the induced morphism $u^*\colon \mathbb{S}_\infty(i+1)\to\mathbb{S}_\infty(i)$ is. Looking at the diagrams, you can verify that it is the map $t_kt_{k-1}\ldots t_1\mapsto t_kt_{k-1}\ldots t_1 u$.
Consider the cube

in which all vertical $1$-morphisms are identities, the backwards pointing $1$-morphisms are the canonical maps, the left square is $H_{j+1}$, the right square is $H_j$, the front square is given by $\alpha$ (only) acting on $u$, and the back square is given by the identity homotopy. Finally, the top and bottom squares are identity homotopies. Then we can find a trivial higher homotopy filling in the cube. This witnesses that the filler in the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{S}_\infty(i) @<{u^*}<<\mathbb{S}_\infty(i+1)\\
@V{\varphi_i}VV @VV{\varphi_{i+1}}V\\
\mathbb{S}_\infty(i) @<{u^*}<<\mathbb{S}_\infty(i+1)
\end{CD}
$$
(in which we already knew that $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_{i+1}$ are both homotopic to $\mathrm{id}_{(S^1)^\infty}$) is itself trivial. This finally proves that $\varphi\colon\mathbb{S}_\infty\to\mathbb{S}_\infty$ is an identity morphism.

Now we go back to the situation of our claim. The categorical suspension functor $\Sigma_\mathrm{cat}\colon\mathsf{An}\to\mathsf{Cat}_{\infty,[0]\sqcup[0]/}$ is left adjoint to the mapping anima functor, and this universal property implies that there is a unique functor $K\colon\mathsf{S}\to\mathscr{C}, i\mapsto K_i$ sending $s\colon i\to i+1$ to $f_i$, and sending $\alpha\colon s\simeq s$ to $\alpha_i$. By (HTT, 5.3.6.2) (you know this is a serious answer, as we are citing Higher Topos Theory), there exists a cocomplete $\infty$-category $\mathscr{P}'(\mathscr{C})$ and a fully faithful functor $y'\colon\mathscr{C}\hookrightarrow\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{C})$ that sends the colimit diagram $\mathbb{N}^\triangleright\to\mathscr{C}$ given by the $K_i$, $K_\infty$, the maps $f_i$ and the maps $g_i$ (and a bunch of homotopies) to another colimit diagram. Via left Kan extension we obtain a cocontinuous functor $K_!\colon\mathsf{PSh}(\mathsf{S})\to\mathscr{P}'(\mathscr{C})$ for which $K_!y\simeq y'K$. Using that $y'$ preserves the particular sequential colimit we are interested in, we see that
$$(y'\psi\colon y'K_\infty\to y'K_\infty)\simeq K_!(\varphi\colon\mathbb{S}_\infty\to\mathbb{S}_\infty)\simeq\mathrm{id}_{y'K_\infty}.$$ Finally, since $y'$ is fully faithful, this implies $\psi\simeq\mathrm{id}_{K_\infty}$, and we have won.
I hope to add a solution to the general question tomorrow.
